# WPF Tab Item trigger not working while the focus is in web page

Tags: wpf, selected, tabitem

In WPF a 'Tab Control' is having two 'TabItems'. Second tab item is having a WebBrowser control to display a web page. In second tab item, Clicking inside the web page/scrolling down the web page and move to first tab item and click on it. It's not working (May be the focus is still in the web page). How to make it working?

Comment: Which not working? `tab item not working`? or `WebBrowser not working`? Please explain.

Comment: First Tab item not working.

Comment: What you mean by "not working", you can't change TabItems? I just created a mini project here and it worked as expected. Do you have some code behind, modification to your TabControl?